# Nested C++ class outer members' access

Tags: c++

This code does not work (MS VS 2005),

```
b->funcA();
B::iterator iter;
```

cant access protected members declared in class A.

If I remove class D, everything compiles nicely.

I wonder if it's just a bug or standard?

```
class A
{
protected:
    void funcA() {  }
    class iterator {    };
};

class D {
    class B : public A {
        class C {
            B* b;
        public:
            void funcC() {
                b->funcA();
                B::iterator iter;
            }
        };
    public:
        void funcB() {
            funcA();
        }
    };
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug, the code compiles fine with GCC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are inner classes in C++ automatically friends?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013717/are-inner-classes-in-c-automatically-friends)

Comment: @Nawaz: Not a dupe, this question is about `class D`.

Comment: it's not a duplicate, it's more complicated case with double nesting.

Answer (score 3):

The current C++ standard (C++03) has the following restriction that would make your code ill-formed:

> The members of a nested class have no special access to members of an enclosing class, nor to classes or functions that have granted friendship to an enclosing class; the usual access rules shall be obeyed (C++03 11.8/1).

However, this rule has been reversed in the forthcoming C++ standard (C++0x).  The paragraph now reads:

> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member. The members of an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules shall be obeyed (C++0x Draft N3225 11.8/1).

So, under the old interpretation, your code is incorrect but under the new interpretation it is correct.  This is basically a defect in the original C++ Standard; the defect was noted in 1998 and the correction was agreed to in 2001.  You can find details on that in [CWG Defect 45](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45).

---

Note that regardless which interpretation you want to use, I think there is still a bug in the compiler.  The following is the minimal repro, and generates the same error when using Visual C++ 2010:

```
class A {
protected:
    void f() { }
};

struct D {
    struct B : A {
        struct C {
            void g() { 
                B().f(); 
            }
        };
    };
};
```

However, if you remove `D` and put `B` in the global namespace, the compiler accepts the code.

Comment: Are you filing the bug report on MS Connect or shall I?  In either case, a link should be placed here so the SO community can upvote it.

Comment: @Ben:  I was going to report it internally, but if you'd like to report it on Connect, that would be good; it would give the issue external visibility and allow the OP to track the issue.

Comment: Oh... I never realized you were a 'softie.  With an MVP and devdiv member both reporting this, it ought to get some action.  [Bug #644861](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/644861/member-access-from-nested-classes-is-affected-by-nesting-depth)

Comment: @Leo: And... we have [an official answer](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/644861/member-access-from-nested-classes-is-affected-by-nesting-depth).  Basically, this part of C++0x wasn't ready in VC++ 2010, the compiler team provided a workaround, and we should expect the next VC++ to handle it properly.

Comment: @Ben:  Thanks for following up.  That's not quite what Ulzii said, though :-)  The C++0x behavior will be implemented in some future release, not necessarily the next release (I hope that all the remaining C++0x features are implemented in the next version, but I'm not holding my breath :-D).  Also, I didn't see your previous comment, but yes, I joined Microsoft in September.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that C is nested in B doesn't give C special access to B's members.

Solutions for funcA():
(1) Make funcA() public.
or (2) Call funcB() instead (delegating to funcA()).

Solution for iterator: Make iterator public.

Comment: What version of the standard are you reading?  Section `[class.access.nest]` of draft n3225 says the opposite.

Comment: @Ben Voight: "INTERNATIONAL ISO/IEC STANDARD 14882 First edition 1998-09-01", since you ask, but I couldn't find it until I saw the answer from Nawaz. Are you getting confused with Java?

Comment: @Ben Voight: He says he's using VC2005. Not sure that supports C++0x.

Comment: @Martin: No, I'm using a much more recent version of the C++ spec (which is still in the final stages of standardization).  And I know VC2005 doesn't support C++0x.  That's why I asked what standard you were referring to instead of just applying a downvote because my copy said otherwise.

Comment: @Ben: Understood. I think I need to get a new copy -- My compiler (VS2008) likewise can't make its mind up. (Error goes away when not nested in D.)

Comment: Well, in VS2005 error goes away too if I remove D class. One more interesting feature (bug): if I derive D from A, C can access iterator but can't access function from class A :o

Answer (score 0):

`C` is nested class of `B`. Nested class cannot access private and protected members of enclosing class. That is why the code doesn't compile, and correctly gives compilation error.

The C++ Standard (2003) says in $11.8/1 [class.access.nest],

> **The members of a nested class have no
>   special access to members of an
>   enclosing class**, nor to classes or
>   functions that have granted friendship
>   to an enclosing class; the usual
>   access rules (clause 11) shall be
>   obeyed. The members of an enclosing
>   class have no special access to
>   members of a nested class; the usual
>   access rules (clause 11) shall be
>   obeyed.

Example from the Standard itself:

```
class E 
{
    int x;
    class B { };
    class I 
    {
        B b; // error: E::B is private
        int y;
        void f(E* p, int i)
        {
           p->x = i; // error: E::x is private
        }
   };
   int g(I* p)
   {
       return p->y; // error: I::y is private
   }
};
```

So according to it, presence or absence of `D` should not effect anything. It should give compilation error, even if D is absent.

Similar topic was created yesterday: [Are inner classes in C++ automatically friends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013717/are-inner-classes-in-c-automatically-friends)

---

By the way, it's a defect in C++03 which has been corrected in C++0x.

This is allowed in C++0x. See this [Access to nested classes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45)

Comment: But this reverses in C++0x.  `I` has access to private members of `E` (`E` still has no special access to members of `I`).  Furthermore, the question says the result depends on the presence of `class D`... which should have no effect under either C++03 or C++0x.