# How access to private members from a struct defined within a class? c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have defined a struct within a class as follows:

```
class my_header {

public:
    my_header();

    struct add_x {
        double operator()() const { return a; }
    } add_x;

private:
    double a{1.0}; 
};
```

When compiling (g++ -std=c++11), I got the following errors:

```
./my_header.h:19:40: error: use of non-static data member 'a' of
      'my_header' from nested type 'add_x'
                double operator()() const { return a; }
```

Is it possible to access private members of the class from the struct defined within the class itself?

Comment: `add_x` is a distinct type that doesn't inherit or otherwise have access to an instance of `my_header`.

Comment: Why are you declaring this additional `struct` layer? That's not a member function, it has no access to any particular `my_header` instance. It only has access to `add_x`.

Comment: `a` is not `static`, so `add_x` needs a pointer/reference to a `my_header` instance in order to access its `a` member. As for the `private` issue, prior to C++11, you would have to explicitly declare `add_x` as a `friend` of `my_header`. In C++11 and later, [`add_x` has access to `my_header`'s members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013717/).

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing how c++ nested classes work with how java nested classes work. Java nested classes are always associated with an instance of the outer class. This isn't the case in c++, nested classes can exist independently from any instance of the outer class.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "*Java nested classes are always associated with **an instance of** the outer class*" - thanks for that! I always wondered how use of `outer.this` inside an `inner` class worked, that always confused me. Now I finally get it.  I was missing the link that an inner class object instance is actually part of an outer class object instance, not a separate object.

Comment: @tadman could you please take a look at this problem  please https://ibb.co/niqDnT

Comment: That image describes something completely different than what you're doing here. Can you explain the connection?

Comment: I did not show any picture! What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `add_x` instance of the `add_x` nested type does not know the correct instance of `my_header` to use for accessing the field `my_header::a`. Which is why it complains about `a` being non-static (if it were static, it would know what `a` you were asking for).

An alternative would be to have `add_x` take a reference to `my_header` in its constructor, and use that instance to access `a`.