# How to access private Constructor from within inner class? C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, inner-classes, builder

I am trying to apply the builder pattern to an object, but the private constructor is not visible from the inner class.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Outer{
private:
    Outer(void){ std::cout << "Constructed!" << std::endl; }
public:
    class Builder{
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<Outer> build(void){
            return std::make_unique<Outer>();
        }
    };
};

int main(int argc, char** agrs){
    std::unique_ptr<Outer> instance = Outer::Builder().build();
    return 0;
}
```

fails with the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/memory:80,
                 from scrap.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object std::make_unique(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = Outer; _Args = {}; typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<Outer>]’:
scrap.cpp:11:35:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/unique_ptr.h:831:30: error: ‘Outer::Outer()’ is private within this context
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scrap.cpp:6:2: note: declared private here
  Outer(void){ std::cout << "Constructed!" << std::endl; }
  ^~~~~
```

I tried `friend class Outer::Builder` in the definition, but `Outer` is incomplete at the friend clause, so I couldn't make it work with that. I would very much like to restrict instantiation of the object to the `Builder` class, is there any way to do that in C++?
Or is making the `Outer` constructor public the only option?

Comment: The problem is that `std::make_unuque` needs to access your private constructor, and it cannot, because it is neither a friend nor a member.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5013735/1467600 says otherwise,  but you are right with c++14.. ( in c++14 there is the same error as pre c++11 )

Comment: In C++03 you would need to make the inner class a friend to refer to the private ctor, but your inner class does not rever to the ctor anyway. `std::make_unique` does.

Comment: @DavidTóth you missed the point what `n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.` wrote you. There is no problem accessing outside class from inner class or vice versa, it is problem that template `std::make_unique` can't access none public constructors.

Comment: OH I missed that! Right...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call ::std::make\_shared on a class with only protected or private constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const)

Comment: @JaMiT Not especially, because the focus of the problem was not on the usage of `std::make_unique`; and using `std::unique_ptr<Outer>(new Outer)` is the simplest solution possible ( which is a whole different solution than the one you linked has ). Thank you for the suggestion anywway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because the real builder is `std::make_unique`, and it is neither a friend nor a member. Making it a friend is not really possible, because you don't know what internal function it delegates to, and it would defeat the purpose of a private constructor anyway.

You can just use bare `new` instead of `std::make_unique`, it will work in a pinch. If instead of a unique pointer you want a shared pointer, this becomes a bit more problematic, since the performance will not be as good.

Here's how to make it work for `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` or any other kind of handle.

```
#include <memory>

class Outer
{
    private:
        Outer();
    public:
        class Builder
        {
            private:
                class InnerOuter;
            public:
                std::unique_ptr<Outer> build();
        };
};

class Outer::Builder::InnerOuter : public Outer
{
    public:
        using Outer::Outer;
};

std::unique_ptr<Outer> Outer::Builder::build()
{
    return std::make_unique<InnerOuter>();
}
```

Now only `Outer::Builder` can refer to (and construct) an `InnerOuter`, because it is a private class. But its constructor is public, so `std::make_unique` can access it.

Note, `InnerOuter` can access a private constructor of `Outer` because it is a member of a member of `Outer` and have member access to `Outer`.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Outer{
private:
    Outer(void){ std::cout << "Constructed!" << std::endl; }
public:
    friend class std::unique_ptr<Outer> std::make_unique<Outer>();
    class Builder{
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<Outer> build(void){
            return std::make_unique<Outer>();
        }
    };
};

int main(int argc, char** agrs){
    std::unique_ptr<Outer> instance = Outer::Builder().build();
    return 0;
}
```

You can make a friend function in C++ too.

Comment: Now you can say `std::unique_ptr<Outer> instance2 = std::make_unique<Outer>();` in `main`. What's the purpose of having a builder then?

Comment: In the example not much, but in the actual code usage, the constructor parameters differ, so this is something I would accept as an answer.

Comment: @DavidTóth Accept what you want, but "constructor parameters differ" has nothing to do with my remark. If you have `std::make_unique` as a friend, you can bypass `Builder`, with any constructor parameters. Just make the constructor public then.

Comment: If `friend` is used I would do it by `friend template< class T, class... Args >
unique_ptr<T> std::make_unique( Args&&... args );`.

Comment: @MarekR It doesn't compile with gcc: `friend template< class T, class... Args > unique_ptr<T> std::make_unique( Args&&... args );`, the one I come up with is somewhat weird but compiles: `template <typename T, typename... Args> friend typename std::_MakeUniq<T>::__single_object std::make_unique(Args&&... args);`

Comment: you are right @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Your answer for with the new operator is the one I went with, exactly because of the privacy concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on details which are not described in question, there are other ways to do solve the issue.

For example the simplest way if virtual calls are fine for you just use factory pattern. This will completely hide implementation details (this is common approach when using dependency injection) object can be constructed since `Outer` is completely abstract.

```cpp
// header
#include <memory>

class Outer {
public:
    virtual ~Outer();

    virtual void fun1() = 0;
    virtual int fun2(int) = 0;

    class Builder{
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<Outer> build(void);
};
```

```cpp
#include "Outer.h"

Outer::~Outer() = default;

class ImplOuter : public Outer {
public:

    void fun1() override {
        // todo
    }
    int fun2(int) override {
        // todo
        return 0;
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<Outer> Outer::Builder::build(void)
{
     return std::make_unique<ImplOuter>();
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Outer.h"

int main(int argc, char** agrs){
    auto instance = Outer::Builder().build();
    instance->fun1();
    return 0;
}
```